# Haskell image processing library?

Tags: haskell, image-processing

Anyone have a recommendation for a good image processing package for Haskell?  Why do you like it?

Answer (score 17):

There are at least two decoders in Hackage: [stb-image](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/stb-image) (Partial implementation of JPEG, PNG, TGA, BMP, PSD decoders, with a really simple API) and [pngload](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/pngload) (pure Haskell loader for PNG images).

Otherwise, you could use Haskell bindings for an existing library, for instance [hsmagick](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/hsmagick) or [gd](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/gd).

There is also [Codec-Image-DevIL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Codec-Image-DevIL) which are Haskell bindings to DevIL library. It allows to load an image into Haskell array or to write an array as an image. Nothing else, but for reading/writing it supports tons of image formats.

Answer (score 4):

I find a lot to like in the [netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/) format and tools: simplicity, simplicity, and simplicity.  There's some [discussion of netpbm in the Real World Haskell book](http://books.google.com/books?id=nh0okI1a1sQC&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=haskell+netpbm&source=bl&ots=sXVEw3iQdN&sig=IsjDWWNDBnI1mNXsFcUQ_cDtgPE&hl=en&ei=CDP1Sf_GAZjCMa3R6c8P&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4), and they have some source code. Since I don't have the book, I don't know if they give a full library.

Comment: Real World Haskell is avaliable online: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/

Comment: I get a little skittish about delegating to an external program operations that I think should be done in a library, but this turned out to be a fantastic solution for me.  stb-image had some C pointer weirdness and can't re-encode the data, and DevIL won't deal with data in memory.  Netpbm give me a nicely simple solution.