# Image processing in Haskell

Tags: haskell, image-processing, computer-vision

I realize this might be a duplicate of [Haskell image processing library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792221/haskell-image-processing-library), but those answers are more than 4 years old, so wondering if anything has changed.

I'm hoping to build a utility to detect nudity in photographs similar to [Nude.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/nudejs/)  (based on the algorithm from [this paper](https://sites.google.com/a/dcs.upd.edu.ph/csp-proceedings/Home/pcsc-2005/AI4.pdf?attredirects=0). In order to do this, I need to detect pixels in an image that are likely skin-colored.

As a newcomer to the Haskell ecosystem, I'm not sure if there is a generally-accepted best library for doing this kind of image processing work, or if one of the many image processing libraries is best suited for this particular sort of task.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There aren't that many so you could probably go through them and find one suitable for you: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=image . Which library you use depends on what you need for your application (performance, ease of use, type safety, etc). I have use `JuicyPixels` in the past, it is simple and pretty quick.